# trim "px" off the end of Jquery var

Tags: jquery, trim

I have a variable which stores the css value of a margin. I want to remove the "px" from the end so that i just have the number to work with. How can i do this?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
var x = "1px";
var y = parseInt(x, 10); // specify radix to prevent unpredictable behavior
```

Comment: "An integer that represents the radix of the above mentioned string. *Always specify* this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and *to guarantee predictable behavior*. Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Due to some issues with IE you might find parseFloat is better. This is because IE uses partial pixels, like 27.86 instead of 28.

Answer (score 9):

**Option 1:**

```
parseInt('200px', 10);
```

The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer. Don't change the 10 found in the above function (known as a "radix") unless you know what you are doing.

*Output* will be: 200.

**Option 2** *(I personally prefer this option)*

```
parseFloat('200px')
```

*Output* will be: 200

The parseFloat() function parses a string and returns a floating point number.

The parseFloat() function determines if the first character in the specified string is a number. If it is, it parses the string until it reaches the end of the number, and returns the number as a number, not as a string.

The advantage of Option 2 is that if you use decimal numbers (e.g. 200.32322px) you will get the number returned with the values behind the decimal point. Useful if you need specific numbers returned.

Answer (score 2):

Using the String.replace() method is an easy way:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: Why the downvote? I can think of several places where parseInt and parseFloat are too picky for general use.

Comment: Heh yea, the same user also downvoted the question along with my answer before Alex Reitbort gave his answer. Probably just a malicious user :P

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using parseFloat()

In situations where you have decimals, like 0.5s for transition-delay, parseInt(x,10) returns zero, where in contrast parseFloat() returns 0.5

```
var x = "0.5s";
var y = parseFloat(x); //returns 0.5
```

Comment: The question is specifically about pixels (`0.5px` is not as common as `0.5s`).